# Angularjs repeat not displaying Space

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use Angularjs for repeating data for tags.
The static html displays space between the anchor tags, but when I try to replace them with "ng-repeat" I don't see the space and the anchor tags are not wrapping in a bootstrap "col-md-3".

I can't figure if Angularjs is rendering the html element late so css can't be applied properly.

Static Html:
This renders formatted correctly:

```
<a href="#"><span class="label label-dark">Books</span></a>
<a href="#"><span class="label label-dark">Tech</span></a>
<a href="#"><span class="label label-dark">New</span></a>
```

This doesn't:

```
<a href="#" data-ng-repeat="tag in product.Tags"><span class="label label-dark">{{tag.Name}}</span></a>
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle for the case not working

Comment: See this Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/wyjSPl6Gpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your static HTML displays space between elements because there *is* white space between a tags in your markup - a newline in this case.

Your angular version is missing any kind of white space around a tags because ng-repeat will not insert any on it's own.

Note the difference in [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FPwAoxxjhpk3Fj79crVK?p=preview):

```
<!-- this: -->
<span>a</span>
<span>b</span>

<!-- will not display the same as this: -->
<span>a</span><span>b</span>
```

The CSS classes you use are not relevant here because:

1. You apply the classes on an element that is inside the a tag already
2. They do not set any margin - check with Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug or what have you

Comment: Sorry for the late response, got busy at work.  This makes sense.  Thanks!